# Where should I ask questions about low level Linux networking in C?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to use Packet MMAP for some high performance low level Linux networking stuff, and I don't know where such a question should be asked... on the primary StackOverflow? or where?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ask on Stack Overflow. C is programming, and Stack Overflow is for programming.